# Error:Classes must not be nested --> Actionscript

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3

I write a actionscript fileIncludeMyFile.as :

```
package CustomComponent
{
    public class IncludeMyFile extends Object
    {

        public function computeSum(a:int, a:int):Number
        {
            return a+b;
        }
    }
}
```

When i add package, i am getting Error: Package cannot be nested

And My Mxml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Application xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" layout="absolute">
 <mx:Script source="CustomComponent/IncludeMyFile.as"/>  
 <mx:TextInput id="tinput1" width="40" height="40" textAlign="right" 
      x="100" y="100"/>
 <mx:TextInput id="tinput2" width="40" height="40" textAlign="right" 
      x="100" y="100"/>
 <mx:TextArea id="toutput" width="60" height="70" textAlign="right" 
      x="100" y="100"/>

 <mx:Button id="myButton" label="chckSum" 
     click="toutput.text(String(computeSum(Number(tinput1.text),
       Number(tinput2.text)));" x="130" y="140"/>

 <mx:Label text="+" width="40" fontWeight="bold" fontSize="20" x="130" 
      y="140"/>

</mx:Application>
```

Actually here, i include the Actionscript file into MXML.

Please let me know where i did wrong.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" label="chckSum" click="toutput.text(String(computeSum(Number(tinput1.text), Number(tinput2.text)));" x="130" y="140"/>
```

means you're using a plain mxml Button component.

Your function should be static as if doesn't seem you need to create an instance to compute a sum, and you have "a" and "b" as parameters, not a and a, Also, I hope you only need ints, otherwise if somewhere else you're expecting Number values(floating point values), you will them rounded.

```
public static function computeSum(a:int, b:int):Number{
   return a+b;
}
```

Are you sure addition is all you need to do ?

It might have been easier to have something like:

```
<mx:Button id="myButton" label="chckSum" click="toutput.text(String(Number(tinput1.text)+ Number(tinput2.text));" x="130" y="140"/>
```

This is just at a glance. it's all a bit dirty and I have no idea what you're actually trying to do.

Answer (score 4):

This is what is causing the error:

```
<mx:Script source="CustomComponent/IncludeMyFile.as"/>
```

The compiler includes the file and interprets it as:

```
<mx:Script>
  <![CDATA[
  package CustomComponent
  {
    public class IncludeMyFile extends Object
    {
        public function computeSum(a:int, a:int):Number
        {
            return a+b;
        }
    }
  }
  ]]>
</mx:Script>
```

The `<mx:Script>` tag is expected to directly declare variables and methods. When the flex compiles an mxml file, it generates an AS file with its own `package` and `class` declarations. The name of a class declared by an mxml file is the name of that mxml file itself. When your include file contains its own `package` and `class` declarations, the compiler interprets it as nested package/class declarations and hence the error.

You cannot declare classes in the script included through `script` tags - you have to declare them separately. The `script` tag's `source` attribute is a way to write the corresponding actionscript in a separate file (which personally I don't prefer to do) and not to include other classes into your app. Use import statements within the `script` tag to do so.

To fix the error, change the AS file contents to:

```
public function computeSum(a:int, a:int):Number
{
    return a+b;
}
```

Now the method `computeSum` is an instance method of the class declared by your mxml file.

Comment: This is the only answer I found that really explains the cause. My solution was to not include the script using a `script` tag and import the package when necessary.

Answer (score 2):

### Adding my findings on this error for future googlers..

Other than the answer above, this error can be the result of a very small syntax error that the compiler doesn't notify about as you'd expect.

For example:

```
public function myFunc(myVar:String=null):void{
  if(myVar==null){
    myVar : String = "Error";
  }
}
```

Notice that the second " : String" is not required and is in fact the syntax error that triggers this compiler error.

Other cases for this error message:

1. Missing semicolon
2. Overuse of inline variables in mxml params
3. Dual imports of namespaces

The best person to figure this problem out is probably the one who wrote the faulty code in the first place. Like finding a needle in a hay sack.

Good luck!

Comment: I remember when I didn't hate my tools. Thank you.